# javascript google script 2d array: combine like values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a google spreadsheet I've created a nested 2D array using javascript.

The sheet 'Hours' is where employees add various hours for different categories.
There's an image with a trigger to the submit() function.
The sheet 'Approve' receives some data from the 'Hours' sheet where a manager can, well, approve.

Here's the script:

```
function cleanArray(actual){
  var newArray = new Array();
  for(var i = 0; i<actual.length; i++){
    if(actual[i] != "") {
      newArray.push(actual[i]);
    };
  };
  return newArray;
}

function addArray(array){
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    sum += Number(array[i]);
  };
  return sum;
}

function createArray(cats, hours) {
  var newArray = new Array();
  for (i in hours) {
    if(hours[i] != "" ) {
      if(cats[i] == '') { cats[i] = "Unclaimed" };
      newArray[i] = new Array(cats[i], hours[i]);
    };
  };
  return newArray;
}

function submit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Hours');
  var employee = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
  var startDate = sheet.getRange('C2').getValue();

  var mondayHours = sheet.getRange('B4:B9').getValues();
  var mondayCats = sheet.getRange('D4:D9').getValues();
  var mondayArray = createArray(mondayCats, mondayHours);
  var mondayTtl = addArray(mondayHours);

  var tuesdayHours = sheet.getRange('B11:B16').getValues();
  var tuesdayCats = sheet.getRange('D11:D16').getValues();
  var tuesdayArray = createArray(tuesdayCats, tuesdayHours);
  var tuesdayTtl = addArray(tuesdayHours);

  var wednesdayHours = sheet.getRange('B18:B23').getValues();
  var wednesdayCats = sheet.getRange('D18:D23').getValues();
  var wednesdayArray = createArray(wednesdayCats, wednesdayHours);
  var wednesdayTtl = addArray(wednesdayHours);

  var thursdayHours = sheet.getRange('B25:B30').getValues();
  var thursdayCats = sheet.getRange('D25:D30').getValues();
  var thursdayArray = createArray(thursdayCats, thursdayHours);
  var thursdayTtl = addArray(thursdayHours);

  var fridayHours = sheet.getRange('B32:B37').getValues();
  var fridayCats = sheet.getRange('D32:D37').getValues();
  var fridayArray = createArray(fridayCats, fridayHours);
  var fridayTtl = addArray(fridayHours);

  var saturdayHours = sheet.getRange('B39:B44').getValues();
  var saturdayCats = sheet.getRange('D39:D44').getValues();
  var saturdayArray = createArray(saturdayCats, saturdayHours);
  var saturdayTtl = addArray(saturdayHours);

  var sundayHours = sheet.getRange('B46:B51').getValues();
  var sundayCats = sheet.getRange('D46:D61').getValues();
  var sundayArray = createArray(sundayCats, sundayHours);
  var sundayTtl = addArray(sundayHours);

  var weekArray = new Array();
  for (i in mondayArray){
    weekArray.push(mondayArray[i]);
  };
  for (i in tuesdayArray){
    weekArray.push(tuesdayArray[i]);
  };
  for (i in wednesdayArray){
    weekArray.push(wednesdayArray[i]);
  };
  for (i in thursdayArray){
    weekArray.push(thursdayArray[i]);
  };
  for (i in fridayArray){
    weekArray.push(fridayArray[i]);
  };
  for (i in saturdayArray){
    weekArray.push(saturdayArray[i]);
  };
  for (i in sundayArray){
    weekArray.push(sundayArray[i]);
  };

  var weekHours = new Array(mondayTtl, tuesdayTtl, wednesdayTtl, thursdayTtl, fridayTtl, saturdayTtl, sundayTtl);
  var weekHoursTtl = addArray(weekHours); //CAPTURE

  var sortWeekArray = ArrayLib.sort(weekArray, 0, true)

  var approve = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Approve');
  approve.getRange('D1').setValue(sortWeekArray);
  }
```

Right now it's just dumping the 2D array into D1 of the 'Approve' sheet.

A sample output:

```
ESL               | 2
-------------------------
Parent Engagement | 8
-------------------------
School Liaison    | 2.75
-------------------------
School Liaison    | 6.25
-------------------------
School Liaison    | 7.25
-------------------------
Tutoring          | 3.25
-------------------------
Tutoring          | 4
-------------------------
Tutoring          | 4.5
-------------------------
Unclaimed         | 2.5
-------------------------
Volunteer Svcs    | 2
```

I'd like to combine the like items from col1 and sum the like values from col2 and I'd like to do it within javascript before outputting the results.

So, the sample output would become:

```
ESL               | 2
-------------------------
Parent Engagement | 8
-------------------------
School Liaison    | 16.25
-------------------------
Tutoring          | 11.75
-------------------------
Unclaimed         | 2.5
-------------------------
Volunteer Svcs    | 2
```

Any ideas? I'm already using the [2D Arrays Library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library) and none of these functions seem to fit the bill.

The weekArray looks like: `{ "category", val ; "category", val ; ... }`

Also, any ideas on [DRYing](http://ardalis.com/files/media/image/WindowsLiveWriter/DRYDontRepeatYourselfMotivator_BA85/dontrepeatyourself_motivator_2.jpg) up the code are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, never found a JS solution and I seem to have stumped at least 21 members of the SO community, but I wound up doing the following:

1. Collecting the array of hours and categories as shown in the `var weekArray = new Array();` and subsequent loops above (which produces the first table above)
2. Dumping them into two columns on a separate sheet: `lkup.getRange('D2').setValue(weekArray);`
3. Using SUMIF functions on the separate sheet for each category `=SUMIF($D$2:$D$43,"Volunteer Svcs",$E$2:$E$43)`
4. Gathering the new SUMIF'd array with JS: `var categoriesArray = lkup.getRange('F2:K3').getValues();`

and proceeding on from there.

I still gotta believe there's a better way out there (and some DRYer JS to do this with), but I didn't find it and you didn't post it. You can always leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a better way, but this works. I tested it with your example data.

```
function getData(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lr=sheet.getLastRow();
  var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,lr-1,2).getValues();
  var data=data.sort();
  data.push(["",""]);
  sumValues(data,lr)
  } 

function sumValues(data,lr){  
 var newData = new Array();
 for(var i=1;i<lr;i++){
 if(data[i-1][0] == data[i][0]){  
 data[i][1]=parseFloat(data[i][1])+parseFloat(data[i-1][1]); 
 newData.push([data[i][0],data[i][1]]);
 i=i+1.
 }
else if(data[i-1][0] !== data[i][0]){  
newData.push([data[i-1][0],data[i-1][1]])};
 }
newData.push(["",""]);  
dupcheck(newData);
}

function dupcheck(data){
var dup=0;
var lr=data.length;
var l=data.length-1;
for(var i=0;i<l;i++){
if(data[i+1][0] == data[i][0]){
var dup =dup+ 1};
}
if(dup>0){
sumValues(data,lr)
}
else{   
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
sheet.getRange(2, 1, lr,data[0].length).clear({contentsOnly:true});
sheet.getRange(2, 1, data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}}
```